# Qt has a type conversion exception

Tags: c++, qt

```cpp
#include <QApplication>
#include "QWidget"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    QApplication application(argc, argv);

    QWidget widget(nullptr);
    widget.resize(200, 200);
    widget.show();

    return QApplication::exec();
}
```

Qt outputs the following warning:

```
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
"ForegroundNeutral" - conversion from "246We10XOSWT,116,0" to QColor failed  (integer conversion failed)
```

My Qt version is 5.15, and my operating system is [Manjaro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manjaro).

Why does this appear? How can I fix it?

Comment: `246We10XOSWT,116,0` in fact doesn't look like a valid color. The question is: Where does it come from?

Comment: I'm on Windows (and never had trouble concerning this) but I noticed there are config. files: [Using qt.conf](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt-conf.html), [Configuration](https://doc.qt.io/QtApplicationManager/configuration.html) Not sure whether this is a "hot trace" but at least something to start with.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I don’t know. Last time I ran the same code without these warnings. The only difference was that I replaced my desktop with a desktop theme that was similar to the default desktop of Mac OS.

Comment: _The only difference was that I replaced my desktop with a desktop theme_ This may have introduced new config files. I don't know how much the config. of Qt is based on the config. of the underlying window manager. I would look on both sides for something suspicious. If you're lucky you even can isolate the problem by doing a full-text search with `246We10XOSWT,116,0` where the config. files are stored. I don't know how this is managed on your platform but on Linux in general I'm used to directories in the user's home dir., mostly starting with a dot (`.`).

Comment: @Scheff'sCat I think I can basically be sure, because I used a desktop style similar to Mac OS theme, which caused Qt to appear these warnings, that theme is called "McSur-light-alt".
I switched to the default theme of manjaro and these warnings disappeared.

Comment: Config files on Linux are often stored as text files. (Something I really like Linux and *ix OSes in general for.) ;-) Hence, a full-text search may offer you more than expected.